# Why does this not work when trying to find the sum of all multiples of 3 and 5 in 1000?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, calculator

There are a lot of questions on here about the project Euler question about finding the sum of all the multiples of 3 and 5 below 1000, but I am a beginner at **Java**, and I attempted to make my own program to try and figure this out.The problem with my code is, it keeps giving the answer `466`. 466 is the wrong answer to this problem, so I'm wondering what I did wrong.

Here is my code.

```
package sumofmultiples;

public class sumofMultiples{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int number = 1; //<- This is the number that we are checking to be a multiple.
        int totalNumber= 0; //<- Total number of multiples counted so far.
        while (number < 1000){
            if ((number % 3) == 0){
                totalNumber++;
                //The number is a multiple of 3.
            } else if ((number % 5) == 0){
                totalNumber++;
                //The number is a multiple of 5
            }
            number++; //<- Move on to the next number.
        }
        System.out.println(totalNumber); //<- Print results
    }
}
```

Comment: You should clarify what 'not working' means. Does it compile? Give the wrong value? Get stuck in a loop?

Answer (score 6):

You are calculating the number of multiples. Not their sum. The totalNumber++ is going to be incremented whenever a number is a multiple of 3 or 5, but the 'multiple' is not stored.

Change `totalNumber++` to `totalNumber += number` and your problem is solved.

```
package sumofmultiples;

public class sumofMultiples{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int number = 1; //<- the number that we are checking to be multiple.
        int totalNumber= 0; //<- Total number of multiples counted so far.
        while (number < 1000){
            if ((number % 3) == 0 || (number % 5) == 0){ 
                totalNumber += number;
            } 
            number++; //<- Move on to the next number.
        }
        System.out.println(totalNumber); //<- Print results
    }
}
```

Comment: Took me a minute to understand what you were saying, but it makes sense now. The question asked for the sum of all the mulitples. so in essence, you had to find all the multiples, NOT THE NUMBER OF MULTIPLES, then add them all up. Thank you very much sir! You broadened my understanding of this language and helped me out greatly! Cheers

Comment: The problem here is more regarding understanding programming logic than the programming language itself. Anyways, Glad I could help...!!! :)

Comment: @Peter_Browning: Please accept the answer if you have found it helpful by clicking on the check mark beside the answer. Cheers !!